# axios maxContentLength supported for xhr?

Tags: axios

Looks like only the http.js adapter supports maxContentLength. I guess my react-native code using axios is going through the xhr.js adapter since when I do a really small value for maxContentLength, no errors happen.

Would it make any sense for the xhr.js adapter to support maxContentLength?

(as in, I don't see it at first blush when I search https://github.com/axios/axios/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=maxContentLength&type=)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please paste the file with the code that should have this somewhere in it: `axios.get()`

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for your note - Is it fundamentally expected that xhr.js already supports maxContentLength, or is that a future feature add vs. the http.js adapter? That's mainly all I am wondering. If it is believed to be implemented already on xhr.js then i'll assume it was something in my own code that was incorrect :-)